# Loop through array of characters in ARM assembly

Tags: arm

i have an assignment which requires me to loop through string of numbers and perform task based on each number. For example, if numbers are "24531", i have to blink the LED lights on my microprocessor boards which are on indices "2", "4", "5", "3" and "1". 
I'm just stuck on the part where i need to loop through these string of numbers and have to interpret them individually in ARM assembly language.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from original code by Colin__s

You can construe the string as byte size elements of some array. 
Use ldrb to load byte from array at element n... 
The code below will branch to "some function" when ASCII value for #4 is encountered.  The code will fail to return; which is one of several things you will need to further resolve.

```
.data
        array:  .string         "123456"
        .equ    len.array,.-array
        .align

.text
        .global  main
main:
        nop

        ldr r2,=array           // pointer
        MOV r0, #0              // initialise loop index to 0
        MOV r1, #len.array      // number of elements 

        Loop:
                ldrb r3, [r2,r0]
                cmp r3, #0x34           // #4
                beq _do_something

        ADD r0, r0, #1           //increment loop index
        CMP r0, r1
        BLE Loop


_exit:
        mov r7, #1
        svc 0

_do_something:
        ldr r10,=0xdeadc0de
```

Comment: Good answer, might be worth a mention that `beq _do_something` won't update `lr` so it needs either a label to branch back to, or use a `bleq` to branch.

Comment: @Colin__s Yes. I was trying to provide some help but not solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely follow your question, but the code for a loop is below. You can add whatever it is you need to do on each iteration before the compare instruction.

```
MOV r0, #0 ;initialise loop index to 0
MOV r1, #100 ;number of iterations

Loop:
ADD r0, r0, #1 ;increment loop index
CMP r0, r1
BLE Loop
```

Comment: That makes sense, but how do i specify which string does it have to loop through.
For example, in C, we do

char x[10] = "123456";
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
       if(x[i] == 4)
            do_something();
}

how do i code something like this in ARM

Comment: What have you got so far? Is the array declared?

Comment: yes the char array is declared in C and passed as parameter to arm assembly function... lets say the parameter has value "12345", then i need to first read first character, which is "1" and pass it to someother function, then read next character, "2" then pass it again to some function... the issue is, i need to read this string character by character and i do not not how to do this in arm assembly

Comment: I guess it's passed as a `const char *` if so, and it's the only argument the address of the first letter will be in `r0`